# x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix Cross compiling ubuntu

Tags: cross-compiling, mingw-w64, libevent

Hi I'm Trying to compile a code with includes libevent libraries.

since util.h includes netdb.h and I don't find the library file any where present in mingw-64 directory. Tried linking debian netdb.h and it fails.

In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/event2/event.h:202:0,
                 from ../Thread_test.cpp:16:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/event2/util.h:64:19: fatal error: netdb.h: No such file or directory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#ifdef __linux__
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#else
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#endif
```

Im using Ubuntu, and below mentioned is the command line I'm using while compiling.

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o thread.exe ../Thread_test.cpp -lws2_32 -levent -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static

Any help with this regard will be helpful.

Comment: How did you configure libevent? It shouldn't try to include `netdb.h` if it's not available.

Comment: @ssbssa
I took the libevent library from github and followed their initialization procedure 


1) ./configure --prefix=new_dir 
2) sudo make && sudo make install

Comment: You need to cross compile libevent (and all other libraries you may use) as well, like `./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=new_dir`.

Comment: @ssbssa
I tried this, but ended up with build fail.
./configure --prefix=/home/abhishek/LibeventsWindowsFiles/ --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 &&sudo make && sudo make install

stdio2.h:104: undefined reference to `__printf_chk'

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/abhishek/Downloads/libevent-master'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1528: recipe for target 'test/regress.exe' failed
make[1]: *** [test/regress.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/abhishek/Downloads/libevent-master'
Makefile:1253: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: @ssbssa Thank you very much your suggestion works :)

Comment: What changed now, what about that `__printf_chk` error?

Comment: @ssbssa I was compiling with wrong library.